# Kill Pane But Not The Last One

Tags: tmux

I have a keybinding like the following.

```
# Quit Pane > Window > Session
bind-key -T root C-d { # Ctrl+d
       kill-pane # Kill the current pane.
}
```

It first kill panes, then windows. I want to kill only panes but not windows (using a keybinding). If it means keeping the last pane, then no problem.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the count of panes before `kill-pane`:

```
# close a pane if there are >1 panes in current window
bind-key -T root C-d if 'n=`tmux list-panes | grep -c ^`; [ $n -gt 1 ]' {
   kill-pane
}
```